# Filtering and appending matching text strings with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a solid method or best approach for filtering strings of text (like names)? I've been reading up on .filter() but I can't seem to get my head around it in practice.

I have a list of names that need to be whittled down based on the selection of last, middle, and first names. User selects a last name, and the full list of names updates to include only those names that match the last name. Same with middle name and last name.

[image]

(In this example I've selected "Gonzalez" as the last name, so my script grabs those names from the "All Results" panel and clones/appends them to the Final Search Set)

I've managed to cobble together something where I find a matching name and clone it into the full list, but it doesn't account for the middle names and last names- all names that match the first "Gonzalez" get appended, including variations I don't want (De Gonzales for example).

```
$("a.forward").click(function (){
    if ($("#last-name").has(":contains('Gonzalez')").length) { 
        $("#final-list").find(":contains('Gonzalez')").clone(true).appendTo(".fullname");
    }
});
```

I'd settle for even being able to demonstrate the expected behavior as this is a prototype that won't be used for production, but I can't figure out how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to meet your requirements. Basically I applied a filter on the elements you were retrieving using `find("Gonzalez")` to make sure they start with `Gonzalez,`.

**Edit:** I also clear the previous results before adding the new ones.

You can change the lastname to `De Gonzalez` and get the corresponding results.

This is not a very good way to do it, but it should work for your demo.

```js
var lastName = "Gonzalez";

$("a.forward").click(function() {
  // clear the previous results
  $('.fullname').empty();

  // find and add new ones
  if ($("#last-name").has(":contains('" + lastName + "')").length) {
    $("#final-list").find(":contains('" + lastName + "')").filter(function(index, el) {
      return $(el).text().startsWith(lastName + ",");
    }).clone(true).appendTo(".fullname");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="forward" href="#">Forward</a>
<p>Lastname list</p>
<ul id="last-name">
  <li>Gonzalez</li>
  <li>Gonzalo</li>
  <li>Gansalo</li>
  <li>De Gonzalez</li>
</ul>
<p>Fullname list</p>
<ul id="final-list">
  <li>Gonzalez, aaaaa</li>
  <li>Gonzalez, bbbbb</li>
  <li>Gonzalez, ccccc</li>
  <li>Gonzalez, ddddd</li>
  <li>De Gonzalez, aaaaa</li>
  <li>De Gonzalez, bbbb</li>
</ul>

<p>Result</p>
<ul class="fullname">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and has me much closer to a solution, however if I set two variables with two very similar names ("Anderson" and "Anders", for example), selecting "Anderson" will still return results for "Anders" as well. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @bcam7 it shouldn't cause any problem because it is checking for "Anderson," or "Anders," so it can't match both. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sure. If I select "Anders", the final list updates with the Anders options (http://i.imgur.com/RFwmQtA.png). If I select "Anderson", the final list updates with the options for Anders _and_ Anderson (http://i.imgur.com/PZMQG6k.png) See what I mean? That's with two different variables set for each.

Comment: @bcam7 do you clear the results before appending new ones?

Comment: Not currently- I'm not sure how.

Comment: @bcam7 I have edited my code to clear the results before adding new ones.